Can Doxygen be configured such that it renders function bodies with embedded formulas
I have a project which includes doxygen-style formulas in the source code. They are not only in the documentation before the function header but also in the function body.
Is there a way to configure Doxygen such that the source code is rendered along with the doxygen comments and the formulas within those comments?
With the Emacs package texfrag (and other Emacs packages as well), I get an approximation of what I want:
A toy-example:
Code:
/*! \brief Solve system of equations \f$f(x) = 0\f$.

  \param[in] `f` left-hand side function object
  \param[in/out] `x` in: initial guess, out: numerical solution of \f$f(x)=0\f$
  \return `true` if numerical solution is reached within tolerance
 */
bool Newton::SolveSimple(const Function& f, Vector x) {

    for(size_t iter=0; iter < m_MaxIter; ++iter) {
        /*! We solve the linearized equation with some initial guess
          \f{align*}
            f(x) &\overset{!}{=} 0\\
            f(x^{(i)}) + Df(x^{(i)})\cdot\underbrace{\left(x^{(i+1)}-x^{(i)}\right)}_{\displaystyle =:-h^{i}} &= 0
          \f}
          How to feed this to the linear solver:
          \f{align*}
            Df(x^{(i)})\cdot h^{(i)} &= f(x^{(i)})\\
            x^{(i+1)} &:= x^{(i)} - h^{(i)}
          \f}
        */
        Vector residuals = f(x);
        Matrix jac = f.jacobian(x);

        LinSolver ls(m_linSolverParameters);

        Vector h = ls.solve(jac,residuals);

        x -= h;

        if( norm(h) < m_epsAbs + m_epsRel*norm(x) )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

Displayed by Emacs with texfrag.el:

In the actual case I am documenting complicated equations in a Modelica model. It would make sense to put the formulas into the \detail part of the function header comment in this simple toy example. But, this is not a solution for the actual case with the Modelica code (which I can't really show here).

In my opinion this question is off topic here, should be on software recommandations

@albert Isn't Doxygen-Config on topic here? Could you give me a pointer to "soiftware recommodations"?

I don't think doxygen is an issue here, it is about rendering formulas which start in the example with doxygen comments / commands. Doxygen renders the formulas by means of converting latex to images (and has also the possibility in HTML to use MathJax).

@albert Yes, I know that one can generate the documentation with Doxygen. But, as I now it, only the function headers are included in the documentation and not the function bodies. I would like to have the body included in the doc together with the rendered formulas. Can Doxygen be configured that way?

@albert By the way, I found what you meant with software recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

@albert Hopefully, the question is now rephrased such that it is appropriate for this site.

maybe the \internal command together with the setting INTERNAL_DOCS can help
